# Hibernate Search Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have 2 columns, one contains people, second contains their intrests.

I need do to search query based on their interests.

(If you need some information and I didn't give it here, I probably gave it here: [Java SQL Query - Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798828/java-sql-query-hibernate))

At this moment I am trying to do this like that:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT new com.mycompany.kwestionariusz.Osoba(o.id, o.imie, o.nazwisko, o.telefon, o.email, o.uczelnia, o.doswiadczenie, o.skadSlyszal) from Osoba as o INNER JOIN o.zainteresowania as z FETCH ALL PROPERTIES WHERE ((o.id) = (id_osoby)) and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?) and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?) and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?) and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?) and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?)");   
        //Query query2 = session.createQuery("SELECT new com.mycompany.kwestionariusz.Osoba(o.id, o.imie, o.nazwisko, o.telefon, o.email, o.uczelnia, o.doswiadczenie, o.skadSlyszal) from Osoba as o INNER JOIN o.zainteresowania as z FETCH ALL PROPERTIES WHERE ((o.id) = (id_osoby)) and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?) and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?) and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?) and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?) and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?)");      
        query.setString(0,"%"+input1+"%");
        query.setString(1,"%"+input2+"%");
        query.setString(2,"%"+input3+"%");
        query.setString(3,"%"+input4+"%");
        query.setString(4,"%"+input5+"%");      

        List<Osoba> osoby = query.list(); // robimy sobie liste na podst zapytania
        wyswietlWybrane(osoby);
```

wyswietlWybrane method:

```
 private void wyswietlWybrane(List<Osoba> osoby) {

        for (Osoba a : osoby) {
            List zainteresowania1 = a.getZainteresowania();        
            System.out.println("\n\n" + a.getId() +". " + a.getImie() + " " + a.getNazwisko() + "\nTelefon: " + a.getTelefon() + "\nEmail: " + a.getEmail() + "\nUczelnia: " + a.getUczelnia() + "\nDoswiadczenie: " + a.getDoswiadczenie() + "\t\n" + "Skad slyszal: " + a.getSkadSlyszal());
            System.out.print("Obszary zainteresowan: ");
            for (Iterator iterator2 = zainteresowania1.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();){
                Zainteresowania nazwa = (Zainteresowania) iterator2.next();
                System.out.print(nazwa.getZainteresowanie() + ".  "); 
            }
        } 
    }
```

ShowAll Method:

```
public void wyswietlWszystkie()
        {             
            try
            {        
                Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                List<Osoba> osoby = session.createQuery("from Osoba").list(); // tworzymy sobie liste z zapytania do bazy ktora wyswietli nam wszystkich

                wyswietlWybrane(osoby); // przekazujym ta liste do innej i wyswietlamy

                session.getTransaction().commit();
                session.close();
            }
            catch (HibernateException e) 
            {       
                HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();  //Destroy this SessionFactory and release all resources (caches, connection pools, etc). 
            }
        }
```

There are some issues with query I use now.

First. 
When I use WyswietlWszystkie method then I got output like that:

```
1. Krystian Example
Telefon: 900900900
Email: example@example.com
Uczelnia: Example School
Doswiadczenie: Example experience   
Skad slyszal: Friends
Obszary zainteresowan: Java.  Android.  Technologie WWW (HTML, CSS, JavaScript).  Projektowanie aplikacji.
```

but when I use my search method and pass list to wyswietlWybrane (in wyswietlWszystkie im passing list to that method too).

I got output like this: (its search for: Java):

```
1. Krystian Example
Telefon: 900900900
Email: example@example.com
Uczelnia: Example School
Doswiadczenie: Example experience   
Skad slyszal: Friends
Obszary zainteresowan: 

1. Krystian Example
Telefon: 900900900
Email: example@example.com
Uczelnia: Example School
Doswiadczenie: Example experience   
Skad slyszal: Friends
Obszary zainteresowan:
```

as you can see its doubled and I cant see "obszary zaintereson".

now search for: Java and Android gaves no results (it should cuz this person has both of them).

for Technologie WWW and Java:

```
1. Krystian Example
Telefon: 900900900
Email: example@example.com
Uczelnia: Example School
Doswiadczenie: Example experience   
Skad slyszal: Friends
Obszary zainteresowan:
```

all classes etc are already included in thread that I gave link at the beginning of my post.

[image: dane osobowe table]
[image: zainteresowania table]

How can I do search query? What it is acting so crazy?

Comment: The polish name variable and method names are very hard to follow for a non-Slavic speaker. Can you translate them to English, including comments?

Comment: Sorry I just saw your comment now, sure Ill do it in few minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"select o from Osoba o " +
"join o.zainteresowania z " +
"where z.zainteresowanie in (:tags) " +
 "group by o " +
 "having count(z)=:tag_count";
```

This solved my problems.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your query I realize a few problems with your HQL that need to be addressed.  See the section here:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

> A fetch join does not usually need to assign an alias, because the associated objects should not be used in the where clause (or any other clause)

So by doing a FETCH ALL PROPERTIES you do not have the ability to filter on the z children in the same query. Your query should look like this then:

```
SELECT new com.mycompany.kwestionariusz.Osoba(
  o.id, o.imie, o.nazwisko, o.telefon, o.email,
  o.uczelnia, o.doswiadczenie, o.skadSlyszal)
from Osoba as o
  INNER JOIN o.zainteresowania as z
WHERE ((o.id) = (id_osoby))
and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?)
and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?)
and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?)
and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?)
and (LOWER(z.zainteresowanie) LIKE ?)
```

The only thing I am not sure about is this property here:

```
(id_osoby)
```

I don't see this being aliased anywhere and I don't see this column in any of your tables.  Are you sure this is needed?

So this will now give you o parent entities that have been filtered by properties of the z children.  The z children are lazy however so you must query for those independently by the z ID or you should be able to lazy fetch them within the same hibernate transaction just by calling the getter method to return the list of z children.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to past here my new Query, I changed it without fetch etc, id_osoby is ID of person in Zainteresowania table, it it the same as ID in Osoba table

Comment: But still after I changed query, result is the same as my problem from this topic. I removed problem with selecting same person twice by SELECT DISTINCT but still some queries are not searched. Also something strange happened with my ID column, it is increasing by 2-3 every person added, it used to increase by 1. I changed nothing, its auto-increase which I have in map file so I dont know what could be possibly wrong

Comment: @arienn I think the select distinct was a good idea, but to really understand what is going on with your HQL query you will need to set the hibernate.showSql property to true and look at your console output to see the actual SQL statements being generated.  This will give you a clue as to what is being retrieved from the database.